# How to pass parameters or values to Python Scrapy Extension?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have built a Scrapy Extension. I am invoking my Extension from the settings.py file from my Scrapy Project. Now I want to pass parameters or values to this SpiderDetails class. How can I achieve this? My settings.py file code is as follows:                                                                                        EXTENSIONS = {
    'tellercoins.extensions.SpiderDetails': 1000,
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Define your spider

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, var, **kw):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__()
        self.var = var
```

#### Define your extension:

```
class SpiderDetails(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        o = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(o.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return o

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        # access your variable here
        print spider.var
```

#### Pass your variable to spider

```
$ scrapy crawl myspider -a var=value
```

Comment: @kev.. What do you mean by **kw in _init_() function for class MySpider? And I want to pass value from my MySpider class. You are passing it to the scrapy run command. How to do that?

Comment: you can access additional arguments via `**kw`.

Comment: @kev.. I tried your suggestion it gives me error : exceptions.AttributeError 'MySpider' object has no attributes..

Comment: @kev.. Thanks. It worked. Actually I was implementing a spider constructor (__init__) and not calling the base constructor (which compiles the rules).. I tried this and it worked..                   def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(var)